# Grant rights on ADFS users on SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, adfs

I have successfully configured **ADFS Authentication** in SharePoint but unable to grant rights to users on ADFS based Site.

There are two zones in my Site:

**Default:** which is there to Enable Windows Authentication in order to enable crawler http://az-spfe-uat:27822/

**Intranet:** which is using ADFS Authentication and I have disabled Windows Authentication in  order to Land the user directly to the ADFS Login Page.

If I grant rights to "Everyone", the site is accessible to all Employees.

But when I try to grant rights to specific user, I am unable to do so.
When I go to Grant rights, there are two options coming for the same user in the People Picker:

username/adfs Role

username adfs EmailAddress

[image]

[image]

**There is no Active Directory user visible**

when I grant rights to above two users, the user is unable to access the Site.

Please Help

Comment: Is there anything inside SharePoint logs for any error messages related to the authentication process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ADFS authentication, the people picker **doesn't validate the input**, it just shows you all the claim types available.
To be able to grant rights, you should type the exact full claim string (like `i:05.t|adfs|some@email.com`) and make sure that the *Account* field in the *User properties* is exactly in this form (where *adfs* is the name of your trusted identity token issuer in SharePoint). But it is make people picker kinda unusable this way.

So, it is better to install and configure **custom claims provider** like [LDAPCP](https://www.ldapcp.com) (of course if your SharePoint Server has network access to your users' Active Directory domain).

Comment: If I grant rights using i:05.t|adfs|some@email.com, what can I use to provide rights to Active Directory Groups? can you suggest.

Comment: It depends of how you've configured your _role_ claim issuance policy in ADFS. Usually it takes a format of `c:0-.t|adfs|groupname` (if you've chosen _Token-Groups - Unqualified Names_). BTW, _adfs_ is the name of your _trusted identity token issuer_ in SharePoint.  P.S. Seriously, it is better to use LDAPCP than doing this claim-perversions manually )

Comment: Hi, you saved my Life! Thanks a lot. I have successfully configured LDAPCP & it worked fine!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: can you help answering this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77457975/configure-adfs-on-2nd-sharepoint-site-certificate-error